# How can I batch rename files in bash?

Tags: bash

I've got some files like this:

```
database1-backup-01-01-2011.sql
database2-backup-01-01-2011.sql
```

...etc. I want to rename them to add AM, like this:

```
database1-backup-01-01-2011-AM.sql
database2-backup-01-01-2011-AM.sql
```

What's the most concise way to do that from the bash shell?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Another option:

```
for i in *.sql ; do
    mv -v $i ${i%.sql}-AM.sql
done
```

This loops through all the .sql files and renames them to end in -AM.sql instead.

**PROTIP:** Use `$(command)` instead of `` `command` `` in your scripts (and command-lines), it makes quoting and escaping less of a nightmare.

Comment: Nice - the most concise way so far.

Comment: The suggested edit is not an "attempt" to reply, but rather an extension of the original answer. It adds an explanation to the answer and not a reply.

Answer (score 8):

Try this little script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES=`ls *.sql`
for FILE in ${FILES}
{
    BASE=`basename ${FILE} .sql`
    mv ${FILE} ${BASE}-AM.sql
}
```

I just typed that from memory so if it doesn't work 100% don't blame me (i.e., back up your data first ;) )

How it works:

Collect all files into a variable (you could put this inside the for instead but I like to keep things easy to read):

```
FILES=`ls *.sql`
```

Loop through each file:

```
for FILE in ${FILES} { ... }
```

Get the filename without .sql:

```
BASE=`basename ${FILE} .sql`
```

Rename the file, adding -AM.sql to the base name:

```
mv ${FILE} ${BASE}-AM.sql
```

Comment: You can remove the line `FILES=\`ls *.sql\`` and replace `${FILES}` by `*.sql`, shell expansion will take care of finding the files.

Comment: This isn't the most concise way, but I do appreciate the readability and explanation. If I'm going to do this from the command line, I'd rather type what chrish shows, but if I were saving it as a script, I'd definitely use your way for readability.

Comment: I quote: __(you could put this inside the for instead but I like to keep things easy to read)__

Comment: @Matt Jenkins: the readability does not increase by adding another `ls` command. Keep it simple. By the way, I think the `{` are bashish, it's better to replace them by `do` and `done`: `for ...; do ...; done`

Comment: Where have I added another ls command?

Comment: @Matt Jenkins: `FILES=\`ls *.sql\`` <-- there. Shell expansion is built-in, no need for this extra `ls`.

Comment: Well forgive me for writing portable code. `ls..` is just one source of files that the script could handle; it would be trivial to change it to use, say, a predefined list of files, or command line arguements, by just editing this variable. No need to change the structure of the for if you want to put the script to another use. Isn't that the point of this site? To give answers that are of interest to the genral populace? If that means making your scripts a little more wordy and a little more understandable then I don't see a problem with `ls..` as it implicitly shows what is being worked on.

Comment: @MattJenkins: Using `ls` (or another command such as `find`) in that way instead of `for file in *` will fail if there are spaces in filenames. You can also do `command | while read -r file` or `while ... done < <(command)`. Also, variables that contain filenames should *always* be quoted (for the same reason - there may be spaces in filenames). To make sure users are auto-notified of replies, use @username.

Comment: I agree - and if there were spaces in the files (which there aren't as the question states) then I'd personally use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` or maybe `find ... -exec "{}" \;`

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Perl script](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.8/) version of [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.8/bin/rename.PL):

```
rename 's/\.sql$/-AM$&/' *.sql
```

Using the [`util-linux-ng`](http://userweb.kernel.org/~kzak/util-linux-ng/) version of [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) (but only if ".sql" only appears at the end of the filename):

```
rename .sql -AM.sql *.sql
```

Using [`mmv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mmv):

```
mmv '*.sql' '#1-AM.sql'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since a Perl script has been suggested, here's a Ruby script to do the same:

```
`ls *.sql`.split("\n").each do |filename|
  new_filename = filename.split('.').join('-AM.')
  `mv #{filename} #{new_filename}`
end
```

Comment: Wow, I never noticed how the Ruby back-ticks make this look like such a seamless integration with shell.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `qmv` from [renameutils](https://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/)

The `qmv` program will open list of filenames of choosen directory in your default text editor and allows you to edit them. When you save this edited file list, it applies new names to actual files.